# Performs daily android studio

Tags: java, android, t-sql, android-studio

I am trying to run this everyday in the morning. How I can do so that for me it makes once a day. Below is my code but it does not work.

```
public final class FetchMail extends TimerTask {
DatabaseHelper myDb;
SQLiteDatabase db = myDb.getReadableDatabase();


public static void main (String... arguments ) {
    TimerTask fetchMail = new FetchMail();

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(fetchMail, getTomorrowMorning4am(), fONCE_PER_DAY);
}


@Override
public void run(){

    Cursor t = db.rawQuery("SELECT ID_TARGET,TARGET,LEAD_TIME FROM TARGET_TABLE WHERE (LEAD_TIME < date('now')) AND AMOUNT > 0", null);

if (t != null ) {
    if  (t.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            String tmpName = t.getString(t.getColumnIndex("TARGET"));


            String selectQuery = ("INSERT INTO GAMIFICATION(ID,HISTORY,STATE_POINTS) VALUES(NULL,'Points: " + tmpName + "',-1)");
            db.execSQL(selectQuery);




        }while (t.moveToNext());
    }
} 

}


private final static long fONCE_PER_DAY = 1000*60*60*24;

private final static int fONE_DAY = 1;
private final static int fFOUR_AM = 4;
private final static int fZERO_MINUTES = 0;

private static Date getTomorrowMorning4am(){
    Calendar tomorrow = new GregorianCalendar();
    tomorrow.add(Calendar.DATE, fONE_DAY);
    Calendar result = new GregorianCalendar(
            tomorrow.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            tomorrow.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            tomorrow.get(Calendar.DATE),
            fFOUR_AM,
            fZERO_MINUTES
    );
    return result.getTime();
}}
```

I have to add something to MainActivity? Because MainActivity is the first page.

Comment: Use AlarmManager instead. specifically setRepeating...

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is "how to run a scheduled background task"?  Relying on an Activity will not help because an Activity would need to be visible to run (see the state table w/the Activity documentation.  You might be happier w/a background [Service](http://eveloper.android.com/guide/components/services.html) and start it from an [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html)

Good luck.